# Android app update dialog (without Google Play), Parse Error

Tags: java, android

I have coded an update dialog in my app which checks a json file on my server to see if an update is available and then shows an update app dialog box. I know that I can send users to playstore by using Intent but I saw facebook and some other apps also show the same dialog with update button and upon pressing that button, the app starts downloading and installing instantly without going to playstore. However when I added a download AsyncTask to download and install my app, it shows parse error.

Here is my code to download and parse:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String path = "/sdcard/MyApp.apk";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return path;
    }

    // begin the installation by opening the resulting file
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String path) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive" );
        Log.d("Lofting", "About to install new .apk");
        getContext().startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: its showing Parse error